# Show a SplashScreen while loading form content

Tags: c#

I have a `SplashScreen` , `MainForm`.

On my `MainForm_Load` I have a method named `Connect();`. This methods makes a verification of the connection of my RFID device with the SerialPort and it takes a few seconds to finish.

While it goes through the `Connect()` method, I want to show my `SplashScreen`. I tried this:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Frm_Splash s = new Frm_Splash();
    s.Show();
    Connect();            
}
```

The `Connect();` method, shows a message using `MessageBox`.
But when the `SplashScreen` is over, it cloeses itself AND closes the MessageBox aswell.

Here's my `SplashScreen` form code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pbLoad.Value < 100)
       {
          pbLoad.Value = pbLoad.Value + 1;
       }
    else
       {
          timer1.Enabled = false;
          this.Close();
       }
}
```

I know it has something to do with the `this.Close();`. I just don't know how to fix it.

Maybe if I use `this.Visible = false`, but then the `SplashScreen` would not close, it would still be processing, just would be invisible... I think there is a better option.

Comment: Seems like there's something more.  If `SplashScreen` is it's own form, then closing it could not be closing the `MessageBox` produced from another form.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I tried, `this.visible = false` instead of `this.Close()` and worked. But I know the SplashScreen still processing it's just insvisible. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Is it actually closing the message box or shuffling it along to the background?  Can you try to minimize things or alt tab around to see if the message box is still there but hiding?

Comment: @BlargleMonster I already checked that. Its closing the MessageBox. Not just minimizing ;\

Comment: You are using Show() so nothing is stopping your application from being used whilst your splash screen is up

Comment: So the Splash is shown, then the MessageBox is shown, then the Splash closes and the MessageBox goes with it?  That doesn't make sense to me.  Check your output window in debug for exceptions.

Comment: @DonBoitnott That's exactly what is happening.... It closes the splashscreen, closes the messagebox, then show the MainForm.

Comment: I'm confused, you have a splash screen that in my head is an overlaying form, and then above that is a messagebox?

Comment: ...and why is there a `Timer` involved?

Comment: @ChristofferLette - His splash screen is probably set to close after X seconds

Comment: @Sayse I have my MainForm, in my MainForm_Load I instantiate my SplashScreen (it's a FORM), and then I `Show()` my splashscreen. While my splashscreen is showing, the main form calls a method named `Connect();` that shows a message using `MessageBox`. When the splash screen is done, it closes itself with `this.Close()´. But the  messageBox closes with the SplashScreen.

Comment: @ChristofferLette just to increases my ProgressBar.

Comment: @Sayse, I get that. But I would like to think that it would be the `Connect()` method returning that would control when the splash screen closes - not some random amount of time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that you are opening your messagebox using `MessageBox.Show()`... 
Instead of this, use `MessageBox.Show(this,"message");`

I imagine what is happening is your messageboxes parent is set to the splash screen as that is the dialog with focus

Comment: Worked Perfect ! Could you explain to me why the `this` parameter?

Comment: [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698.aspx) - Basically your MessageBox had the wrong parent, it must take the parent from whatever dialog has focus at the time it is shown

Comment: No worries, you may wish to insert `this` into all of your Show() calls to make sure they always have the right parent :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my splash screen:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class frmSplashScreen : Form
    {
        private static frmSplashScreen splashScreen = null;
        private static Thread splashThread = null;
        private Double opacityInc = .03;
        private Double opacityDec = .1;
        private const Int32 iTimerInterval = 30;

        public frmSplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Opacity = .0;
            timer1.Interval = iTimerInterval;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void frmSplashScreen_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CenterToScreen();
        }

        public static void ShowSplashScreen()
        {
            if (splashScreen != null)
                return;
            splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(frmSplashScreen.ShowForm));
            splashThread.IsBackground = true;
            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.Start();
        }

        private static void ShowForm()
        {
            splashScreen = new frmSplashScreen();
            Application.Run(splashScreen);
        }

        public static void CloseForm()
        {
            if (splashScreen != null)
                splashScreen.opacityInc = -splashScreen.opacityDec;
            splashThread = null;
            splashScreen = null;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (opacityInc > 0)
            {
                if (Opacity < 1)
                    Opacity += opacityInc;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Opacity > 0)
                    Opacity += opacityInc;
                else
                    Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I activate it by calling this in the constructor of the Form where I want it to pop-up from:

```
frmSplashScreen.ShowSplashScreen();
```

Then close it in `Shown` of the same Form:

```
frmSplashScreen.CloseForm();
```

NOTE:  I offer this because it employs `static` classes, and that helps to alleviate the ownership issues.

Comment: Thank you !  I'll try to improve some of your code in mine. +1

Comment: [Credit where credit is due](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C) Don... ;)

Comment: @Sayse. I'll admit, it was originally from an Internet source, but not that one.  My guess...it's made the rounds quite a bit.  It's good code.